# Change Settings' color scheme in Lollipop

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, customization, color

Someone was fiddling with my Android (version 5.1.1) phone and somehow managed to change the Settings' color scheme.

I've tried to reset the theme to no avail. I've also noticed some notifications come through with white text (assuming related issue).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, looks like you are using a phone with CM based rom.
Make sure you don't have any theme applied.
A dark/light theme mode option might be available in Display, personalization or Developer settings